# Obj-c - Show 'Pay with Apple Pay' button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've setup Apple Pay in my app, and after reading the documentation, it says not to just use a .png for the 'Pay with Apple Pay' button, but rather to use their documentation code to show the button (as then, it is exactly to spec). I can't seem to find the code for the Pay With Apple Pay button (obj-c) anywhere?

Comment: Take a look on this documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH3-SW2

Comment: @VatsalK Even there I don't see any examples of the pay button in use? Am I missing it?

Comment: you can take reference of this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentbutton/1617848-buttonwithtype?language=objc
I guess you need to instantiate a button with specific type and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH3-SW2

> To create an Apple Pay–branded button for initiating payment request
>   on iOS 8.3 or later, use the PKPaymentButton class

ref:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentbutton

e.g.

```
PKPaymentButton *button = [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType: PKPaymentButtonTypePlain style:PKPaymentButtonStyleBlack];
```